Seleccionar una opción de input radio y mostrar otro grupo de input radio
Necesito que al escoger una opción de mi tres input radio, me muestre un fieldset con otros input radio diferentes. Es por eso que utilizo la condición if, para que me muestre un fieldset diferente por cada opción.
Ya sea con jQuery o JavaScript.
Lo intenté con PHP utilizando la variable $_REQUEST, pero al parecer se necesita enviar los datos  para que recupere los datos y no me funcionó.
Es un formulario dinámico. Por eso debo crear primero un fieldset y después otro de acuerdo a la opción.
Éste es el código que he intentado:


$(document).ready(function() {
      var current = 1,
        current_step, next_step, steps;
      //steps = $("fieldset").length;
      $(".next").click(function() {
            current_step = $(this).parent();
            current_step.hide()
            var a = document.getElementById("sencillo");
            var b = document.getElementById("singraduacion");
            var c = document.getElementById("progresivo");
            next_step = $(this).parent().show();

            if ($(a).is(':checked')) {
              $("#opcion1").show();

              //next_step.opcion1.style.display='block';
              if ($(b).is(':checked')) {
                // next_step.opcion2.style.display='block';
                $("#opcion2").show();
                next_step.show();
              }
              if ($(c).is(':checked') {
                  $("#opcion3").show();

                  //next_step.opcion3.style.display='block';
                } else {
                  echo "no se pudo";
                }

                setProgressBar(++current);

              }
            });
#regiration_form fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
<form id="regiration_form" novalidate action="viewCart.php" method="POST">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    </div>
  </div>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>TIPO DE LENTE</legend>
    <div class="form_group">
      <!--mica sencilla 800 -->
      <!-- solo armazon precio -->
      <label for="sencillo"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="sencillo" value="sencillo" name="tipo_lente" aria-required="true" />Visión Sencilla<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <!--mica   -->
      <label for="singraduaciom"><input type="radio" class="form-control"  id="singraduaciom" value="singraduaciom" name="tipo_lente" aria-required="true" />Sin graduación<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <!-- es de opciones -->
      <label for="progresivo"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="progresivo" value="progresivo" name="tipo_lente" aria-required="true" />Progresivo<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="SIGUIENTE" />
  </fieldset>
  <?php 
                          //var opcion1 = document.getElementByID("sencillo");
                          //var opcion2 = document.getElementByID("bifocal");
                          //var opcion2 = document.getElementByID("progresivo");
                    
                         // if(isset($_REQUEST['sencillo'])){?>
  <fieldset id="opcion1" class="opcion1">
    <legend>ELIGE TIPO DE MATERIAL</legend>

    <div class="form_group">
      <label for="plastico"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="plastico" value="plastico" name="material" required />Plástico CR-39<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <!-- 2100 -->
      <label for="policarbonato"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="policarbonato" value="policarbonato"name="material" required />Policarbonato<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <label class="Graduación Alta" for="Graduación Alta"><input type="radio" class="form-control"  id="Graduación Alta" name="graduacion"  value="Graduación Alta" />Graduación Alta</label>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="SIGUIENTE" />
    <br>
    <BR>
    <a class="previous anterior" value="Anterior">
      <-- REGRESAR A</a>
  </fieldset>


  <?php //} elseif(isset($_REQUEST['singraduaciom'])){?>
  <fieldset id="opcion2" class="opcion2">
    <legend>ELIGE TIPO DE MATERIAL</legend>

    <div class="form_group">
      <label for="plastico"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="plastico" value="plastico" name="material" required />Plástico CR-39<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <!-- 2100 -->
      <label for="policarbonato"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="policarbonato" value="policarbonato"name="material" required />Policarbonato<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <label class="Graduación Alta" for="Graduación Alta"><input type="radio" class="form-control"  id="Graduación Alta" name="graduacion"  value="Graduación Alta" />Graduación Alta</label>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="SIGUIENTE" />
    <br>
    <BR>
    <a class="previous anterior" value="Anterior">
      <-- REGRESAR A</a>
  </fieldset>
  <?php // } elseif(isset($_REQUEST['progresivo'])){?>
  <fieldset id="opcion3" class="opcion3">
    <legend>ELIGE Tratamiento</legend>

    <div class="form_group">
      <label for="digital"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="digital" value="digital" name="tratamiento" required />Plástico CR-39<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>

    <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="SIGUIENTE" />
    <br>
    <BR>
    <a class="previous anterior" value="Anterior">
      <-- REGRESAR A</a>
  </fieldset>
  <?php //} else(isset($_REQUEST['armazon'])) ?>
  <fieldset class="opcion4">
    <legend>ELIGE Tratamiento</legend>

    <div class="form_group">
      <label for="armazon"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="armazon" value="armazon" name="armazon" required />Armazon<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>

    <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="SIGUIENTE" />
    <br>
    <BR>
    <a class="previous anterior" value="Anterior">
      <-- REGRESAR A</a>
  </fieldset>

  <?php// ?>


</form>



También lo he intentado así:


$(document).ready(function() {
      var current = 1,
        current_step, next_step, steps;
      //steps = $("fieldset").length;
      $(".next").click(function() {
            current_step = $(this).parent();
            current_step.hide()
            // var a = document.getElementById("sencillo");
            //var b = document.getElementById("singraduacion");
            //var c = document.getElementById("progresivo");
            next_step = $(this).parent().show();

            if ($(a).is(':checked')) {
              $("#opcion1").show();

              //next_step.opcion1.style.display='block';
              if ($(b).is(':checked')) {
                // next_step.opcion2.style.display='block';
                $("#opcion2").show();
                next_step.show();
              }
              if ($(c).is(':checked') {
                  $("#opcion3").show();

                  //next_step.opcion3.style.display='block';
                } else {
                  echo "no se pudo";
                }

                setProgressBar(++current);

              }
            });
#regiration_form fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
<form id="regiration_form" novalidate action="index.php" method="POST">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    </div>
  </div>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>TIPO DE LENTE</legend>
    <div class="form_group">
      <!--mica sencilla 800 -->
      <!-- solo armazon precio -->
      <label for="sencillo"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="sencillo" value="sencillo" name="tipo_lente" aria-required="true" />Visión Sencilla<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <!--mica   -->
      <label for="singraduaciom"><input type="radio" class="form-control"  id="singraduaciom" value="singraduaciom" name="tipo_lente" aria-required="true" />Sin graduación<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <!-- es de opciones -->
      <label for="progresivo"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="progresivo" value="progresivo" name="tipo_lente" aria-required="true" />Progresivo<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="SIGUIENTE" />
  </fieldset>
  <?php 
                                  //var opcion1 = document.getElementByID("sencillo");
                                  //var opcion2 = document.getElementByID("bifocal");
                                  //var opcion2 = document.getElementByID("progresivo");
                            
                                 // if(isset($_REQUEST['sencillo'])){?>
  <fieldset id="opcion1" class="opcion1">
    <legend>ELIGE TIPO DE MATERIAL</legend>

    <div class="form_group">
      <label for="plastico"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="plastico" value="plastico" name="material" required />Plástico CR-39<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <!-- 2100 -->
      <label for="policarbonato"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="policarbonato" value="policarbonato"name="material" required />Policarbonato<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <label class="Graduación Alta" for="Graduación Alta"><input type="radio" class="form-control"  id="Graduación Alta" name="graduacion"  value="Graduación Alta" />Graduación Alta</label>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="SIGUIENTE" />
    <br>
    <BR>
    <a class="previous anterior" value="Anterior">
      <-- REGRESAR A</a>
  </fieldset>


  <?php //} elseif(isset($_REQUEST['singraduaciom'])){?>
  <fieldset id="opcion2" class="opcion2">
    <legend>ELIGE TIPO DE MATERIAL</legend>

    <div class="form_group">
      <label for="plastico"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="plastico" value="plastico" name="material" required />Plástico CR-39<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <!-- 2100 -->
      <label for="policarbonato"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="policarbonato" value="policarbonato"name="material" required />Policarbonato<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <label class="Graduación Alta" for="Graduación Alta"><input type="radio" class="form-control"  id="Graduación Alta" name="graduacion"  value="Graduación Alta" />Graduación Alta</label>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="SIGUIENTE" />
    <br>
    <BR>
    <a class="previous anterior" value="Anterior">
      <-- REGRESAR A</a>
  </fieldset>
  <?php // } elseif(isset($_REQUEST['progresivo'])){?>
  <fieldset id="opcion3" class="opcion3">
    <legend>ELIGE Tratamiento</legend>

    <div class="form_group">
      <label for="digital"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="digital" value="digital" name="tratamiento" required />Plástico CR-39<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>

    <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="SIGUIENTE" />
    <br>
    <BR>
    <a class="previous anterior" value="Anterior">
      <-- REGRESAR A</a>
  </fieldset>
  <?php //} else(isset($_REQUEST['armazon'])) ?>
  <fieldset class="opcion4">
    <legend>ELIGE Tratamiento</legend>

    <div class="form_group">
      <label for="armazon"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="armazon" value="armazon" name="armazon" required />Armazon<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>

    <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="SIGUIENTE" />
    <br>
    <BR>
    <a class="previous anterior" value="Anterior">
      <-- REGRESAR A</a>
  </fieldset>

  <?php// ?>


</form>




Que hiciste con el snippet XDD como lo rompiste asi ? XDD

quieres que al seleccionar el radio input se muestre el fieldset, o que dependiendo del radio seleccionado se muestre el fieldset correspondiente al apretar el botón?

Quetal ffflabs . si lo que quiero es que dependiendo del radio seleccionado se muestre el fieldset correspondiente al apretar el boton

En esta línea falta el paréntesis de cierre del condicional: if ($(c).is(':checked') {. Estás mezclando código PHP con JavaScript (hay un echo "no se pudo"). Y no tengo claro que los if anidados deban anidados o if else.

El código contiene algunos errores que hacen que no funcione. Estos son los que he encontrado y parece que con ellos deberías desbloquearte:

Falta el cierre del $(document).ready. Esto puede ser porque no se haya copiado bien el código a la pregunta. La solución fue añadir un }) al final.
En el código JS tratas de leer el input con id singraduacion pero en el código HTML el id es singraduaciom (con m en vez de n). La solución para esto: actualiza el id en el HTML para que sea singraduacion (y no te olvides del valor del for en el label).
Estás mezclando PHP con JavaScript: estás intentando escribir usando echo "no se pudo" lo que dará error de sintaxis. La solución: usa console.log("no se pudo") y no mezcles lenguajes.
Falta un cierre de paréntesis en una condición: if ($(c).is(':checked') { que lanzará otro error en la consola. La solución es añadir el paréntesis que falta: if ($(c).is(':checked')) {.
La lógica para mostrar los fieldset es incorrecta: ahora mismo se comprueba el valor del primer radio y si está marcado se comprueban los valores del segundo y tercero (que obviamente no lo estarán). La solución es cambiar la lógica para que todos se comprueben de forma independiente en vez de de forma anidad. Usa if (condición 1) { ... } else if (condición 2) { ... } else if (condición 3) { ... } else { ... }

Con estos cambios, el código queda así y ya "funciona". Te falta la lógica para esconder los campos o prevenir que los radios originales se cambien, pero eso queda fuera del alcance de la pregunta:

Nota: borré el código comentado de PHP para que no causara problemas de visualización.



$(document).ready(function() {
  var current = 1,
    current_step, next_step, steps;
  //steps = $("fieldset").length;
  $(".next").click(function() {
    current_step = $(this).parent();
    current_step.hide()
    var a = document.getElementById("sencillo");
    var b = document.getElementById("singraduacion");
    var c = document.getElementById("progresivo");
    next_step = $(this).parent().show();

    if ($(a).is(':checked')) {
      $("#opcion1").show();

      //next_step.opcion1.style.display='block';
    } else if ($(b).is(':checked')) {
      // next_step.opcion2.style.display='block';
      $("#opcion2").show();
      next_step.show();
    }
    else if ($(c).is(':checked')) {
      $("#opcion3").show();

      //next_step.opcion3.style.display='block';
    } else {
      console.log("no se pudo");
    }

    setProgressBar(++current);


  });
});

// definida para evitar error
function setProgressBar() {};
#regiration_form fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="regiration_form" novalidate action="viewCart.php" method="POST">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    </div>
  </div>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>TIPO DE LENTE</legend>
    <div class="form_group">
      <!--mica sencilla 800 -->
      <!-- solo armazon precio -->
      <label for="sencillo"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="sencillo" value="sencillo" name="tipo_lente" aria-required="true" />Visión Sencilla<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <!--mica   -->
      <label for="singraduacion"><input type="radio" class="form-control"  id="singraduacion" value="singraduaciom" name="tipo_lente" aria-required="true" />Sin graduación<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <!-- es de opciones -->
      <label for="progresivo"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="progresivo" value="progresivo" name="tipo_lente" aria-required="true" />Progresivo<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="SIGUIENTE" />
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="opcion1" class="opcion1">
    <legend>ELIGE TIPO DE MATERIAL</legend>

    <div class="form_group">
      <label for="plastico"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="plastico" value="plastico" name="material" required />Plástico CR-39<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <!-- 2100 -->
      <label for="policarbonato"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="policarbonato" value="policarbonato"name="material" required />Policarbonato<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <label class="Graduación Alta" for="Graduación Alta"><input type="radio" class="form-control"  id="Graduación Alta" name="graduacion"  value="Graduación Alta" />Graduación Alta</label>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="SIGUIENTE" />
    <br>
    <BR>
    <a class="previous anterior" value="Anterior">
      <-- REGRESAR A</a>
  </fieldset>


  <fieldset id="opcion2" class="opcion2">
    <legend>ELIGE TIPO DE MATERIAL</legend>

    <div class="form_group">
      <label for="plastico"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="plastico" value="plastico" name="material" required />Plástico CR-39<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <!-- 2100 -->
      <label for="policarbonato"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="policarbonato" value="policarbonato"name="material" required />Policarbonato<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form_group">
      <label class="Graduación Alta" for="Graduación Alta"><input type="radio" class="form-control"  id="Graduación Alta" name="graduacion"  value="Graduación Alta" />Graduación Alta</label>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="SIGUIENTE" />
    <br>
    <BR>
    <a class="previous anterior" value="Anterior">
      <-- REGRESAR A</a>
  </fieldset>


  <fieldset id="opcion3" class="opcion3">
    <legend>ELIGE Tratamiento</legend>

    <div class="form_group">
      <label for="digital"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="digital" value="digital" name="tratamiento" required />Plástico CR-39<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>

    <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="SIGUIENTE" />
    <br>
    <BR>
    <a class="previous anterior" value="Anterior">
      <-- REGRESAR A</a>
  </fieldset>


  <fieldset class="opcion4">
    <legend>ELIGE Tratamiento</legend>

    <div class="form_group">
      <label for="armazon"><input type="radio" class="form-control" id="armazon" value="armazon" name="armazon" required />Armazon<span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    </div>

    <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="SIGUIENTE" />
    <br>
    <BR>
    <a class="previous anterior" value="Anterior">
      <-- REGRESAR A</a>
  </fieldset>



</form>




muchas gracias. claro que si, nos falta mejorar, poco apoco
